# V8/Chakra vs CLR - What will be the impact of TypeScript

Tags: .net, typescript

Watching the various presentations on TypeScript, it seems to me that if V8, Chakra or any of the javascript engines match (come close to?) the performance of the CLR (anyone know if they do?), surely this encroaches on the .Net space?

Static typing seemed to be a big differentiator between the .Net dev world and the js world. Given now that TypeScript comes with the benefits of

- static typing
- cross platform
- access to the js eco system (in a statically typed manner)
- (given that the compiler is in TypeScript (with a .d file available), I wasn't sure if you effectively almost got "compiler as a service")

I was wondering if someone could explain a problem space better approached using the .Net toolset/eco system? Or is it more down to what one is used to/where "one is at"?

Thx

S

Answer (score 4):

The C# and Java development platforms are the result of 50 years of continuous evolution in language design and software engineering. They are probably the best platforms available today for writing large bodies of program code, say 25,000 lines upwards.

TypeScript just solves two problems when adopting JavaScript for large scale development, namely strong typing and object oriented extensions. As a C# programmer I want LINQ, Generics and CodeContracts. TypeScript falls short as a replacement but it does substantially shift the boundary as to where JavaScript and C# are best used.

I say this as a C# programmer who views TypeScript as the most significant news event since LINQ.

Comment: Thx very much. Wrt LINQ are there not js-type libs which give you something like that (eg underscore, linqjs, rxjs)?

Comment: As a short answer, linqjs can not be an equivalent of linq in some aspects. lambda expressions should be supported runt time. but typescript supports arrow functions that are not lambda expression just they are similar. linqjs accept lambda expression as a script that it does not have type checking. And linqjs can not support it in this way because JavasScript does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing new under the sun with Typescript.  It is just a language translator, it doesn't include a VM implementation.  Output is regular Javascript, it won't run any faster or slower than hand-crafted JS.

The most important value-add for Typescript is development-time improvements.  Catch bugs early thanks to typing, but it is still optional, reliable auto-completion and refactoring support.  Everything you'd need to trust a language to be used in large projects that are still maintainable.  And yes, aspects of compiler as a service is there, well demonstrated by Anders when he ran Typescript in Google's Chrome with Typescript in the left pane and the generated Javascript in the right pane, produced instantly while typing.

Comment: Thx Hans ... the thing that struck me though was that it nullified one of the big wins of .net dev - by offering static typing and the tooling that goes with it. If .net runtime perf is matched because of improvements in js execution engines, why choose .net  - other than that is what you are used to/ what your legacy app is written in? (not that those aren't good reasons!)

Comment: Static typing can only improve perf when there's a VM that can take advantage of it.  Convincing companies like Apple, Google, Mozilla, Opera to support such a VM on any operating system is, erm, difficult.  Compare this to the x86 processor architecture.  It didn't win because it was a great design, it won because it became ubiquitous.

Comment: Not sure I made myself clear. I wasn't suggesting that static typing was related to perf in this instance - rather that static typing offers tooling benefits (which are now available via ts) plus, and completely independently, js execution improvements (if comparable with clr execution perf) mean that ts (and therefore js) dev nullify benefits in .net dev in those areas. Wondering what if any areas there are still wins for .net dev. Eg One could argue that C# is a better dev language than ts

Comment: Typescript cannot and does not alter the typing system of Javascript.  It is still stuck with *number*, a double.